# Why isn't xcode allowing me to use actionCodeSettings (copied directly from firebase docs and replaced with my info)?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here below is all my code for the view controller, I imported firebase thinking that would work but it's saying "expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration, expected '(' in argument list of function declaration, consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';', cannot find 'ActionCodeSettings' in scope.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var SignUpLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LastNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PhoneNumberField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailField: UITextField!

    
    let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
    actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(com.IMHOTECHP.GiveMe!)
    actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
    actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "giveme-d7861.firebaseapp.com")
   
    
    private func createTextDelegate(){
        FirstNameField.delegate = self
        LastNameField.delegate = self
        PhoneNumberField.delegate = self
        EmailField.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    // Allows return button to dismiss keyboard once tapped.
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    // Tap Gesture method to dismiss keyboard once you click outside of text field.
    private func configureTapGesture(){
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignUpViewController.handleTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    // Objective C function to allow for selector to be called
    @objc func handleTap(){
        print("handle tap was called")
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func SignUpButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    // Changes text field input color to the same color as the placeholder text
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        FirstNameField.textColor =  UIColor(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        LastNameField.textColor =  UIColor(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        PhoneNumberField.textColor =  UIColor(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        return true
    }
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       createTextDelegate()
        configureTapGesture()
        
    }
    
   
    /*

}
// Extension to UITextField for adding specific protocols
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var placeHolderColor: UIColor? {
        get{
            return self.placeHolderColor
        }
        set{
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: newValue!])
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four lines starting at

```
let actionCodeSettings
```

are wrong. Executable code needs to be inside a method, not free floating at the top of the class declaration.

Comment: thanks matt and one more thing its saying can't find com in scope for the setIOSBundleID

Comment: Sounds like a simple typing mistake.